How to translate struct to type []byte?
I read this article on using httptest to mock outbound HTTP requests, but the line of code containing the request I'd like to mock returns a struct called gophercloud.ProviderClient:
func Authenticate() (*gophercloud.ProviderClient, error) {
    provider, err := openstack.AuthenticatedClient(authOpts)
}

The test function I'm writing for this line of code is this:
func TestGetAuthClient(t *testing.T) {
    //Fixed value that should be returned 
    mockProvider := &gophercloud.ProviderClient{}

    //Create server object to intercept request
    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.URL.Path != "https://endpoint-to-get-authenticated-client/api" {
            t.Errorf("Expected to request '/fixedvalue', got: %s", r.URL.Path)
        }

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte(mockProvider)) // Error here
    }))

    defer server.Close()

    client, err := Authenticate()
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Provider client failed")
    }
    if client != nil {
        t.Errorf("Expected 'fixed', got %v", pc)
    }
}

However trying to write the fixed test value into the w.Write([]byte(mockProvider)) will throw cannot convert mockProvider (variable of type *gophercloud.ProviderClient) to type []byte. Unfortunately I didn't really understand reading the documentation for w.Write.

How about converting struct to json?
byteMockProvider, _ := json.Marshal(mockProvider)
w.Write(byteMockProvider)

